# Ostensive purposes

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, legalese

What is the exact meaning of "ostensive purposes" in the sentence: "The ostensive purpose for his departure was catching the train". How would "ostensive" compare to "ostensible" in the sentence in question?

Answer (score 1):

*Ostensive* and *ostensible* ought to mean different things, and each has had in its history some meanings which the other does not share. Most of those meanings, however, are technical, belonging to law and philosophy.

In ordinary speech, both words are quite rare. The only use most people ever encounter is the one used in your example: *ostensible purpose*, meaning the purpose someone professes, acknowledges, "points to".

I myself use only *ostensible* in this sense, and reserve *ostensive* for the meaning *demonstrating, pointing out*, as in *ostensive definition*. But people have been using *ostensive* to signify what I mean by *ostensible* for two hundred years, so it cannot be characterized as a mistake.

Nonetheless, if I were you, I would stick to *ostensible* for this meaning. It is 7 or 8 times more common than *ostensive*, and even the technical meanings are reasonably close to the common meaning; so people are are far more likely to understand you if you use *ostensible*.